# react-admin + supabase filtering FilterListItem issue with query

Tags: filter, react-admin, supabase

I'm writting a FilterSidebar based on the doc's examples, I'm using supabase (local).

```
export const PaymentFilterSidebar = () => (
<Card sx={{ order: -1, mr: 2, mt: 9, width: 200 }}>
<CardContent>
  
  <FilterListItem
    label='This Month'
    value={{
      'paymentDate@gte': startOfMonth(new Date()).toISOString(),
      'paymentDate@lte': undefined,
    }}
  />

  <FilterListItem
    label='Last Month'
    value={{
      'paymentDate@gte': startOfMonth(
        subMonths(new Date(), 1),
      ).toISOString(),
      'paymentDate@lt': startOfMonth(new Date()).toISOString(),
    }}
  />
```

the second item throw an Error in RA

> time zone "lt.2023-12-31t16:00:00.000z" not recognized

if I mix `paymentDate@lt` and `startDate@lt` (which is another date available in that table) as so

```
value={{
          'paymentDate@gte': startOfMonth(
            subMonths(new Date(), 1),
          ).toISOString(),
          'startDate@lt': startOfMonth(new Date()).toISOString(),
        }}
```

I don't get the error. Permuting paymentDate@gte and paymentDate@lt will throw the error on the gte (time zone "gte.2023-12-31t16:00:00.000z")

after checking some postgrest example, I think it should be possible to use paymentDate with gte and lt in the same "value" so is it an issue wiht RA or did I do something wrong?

Thanks for the help

EDIT:
I'm trying with different fields, and error is always the same, as soon as the value has two times the same column, to check a lte and gt for example then I get the error.
to avoid issues with Date formats I am trying to understand with a simple number field (price) from the payments table, and trying to filter to get all the records with a price between 2000 and 6000,

when pressing the filter button, the console error is:
http://localhost:54321/rest/v1/payments?price=lt.6000**%2C**gte.2000

if i copy the url, and replace the **%2C** by a **&** then I have the list of the records matching the filter.

Do that means there is an issue with ra-supabase? Do i need to write a special component to manually query the api?

thanks

Comment: If you don't get the error when replacing `paymentDate@lt` by `startDate@lt` this tends to indicate the error may come from your database schema rather than from react-admin. Are yous sure the two columns are exactly the same type?

Comment: The database schema is correct, both date format are the same. the error is thrown on the second element of "value" if it the first element is from the same column ex: paymentDate@gte + paymentDate@lt or startDate@gte + startDate@lt but no error if we mix paymentDate@gte + startDate@lt.

I edited my post to explain a bit better

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I looked a little deeper into it, and it seems to me you have found a bug in the `ra-supabase` library! I filed an [issue](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-supabase/issues/46) on their repo, along with a [PR](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-supabase/pull/47). You can follow its resolution state from there.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much! I’ve subscribed to the issue on GitHub, I’ll wait for the fix to be done passed onto ra-supabase. Thanks so much for your help.